# How to add a column with the time to a pandas dataframe (created from a JSON)?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I retrieve data (JSON format) from a software API and transform it into a dataframe to write it in a CSV (pandas library). I would add a column with the time. I would like it to be written "time" on the first row and for example "Fri Mar 29 09:16:02 2019" on the following ones. An idea on how to achieve this?

I got to add the time but just on the first row of my dataframe.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
import time
import urllib.request

url='http://localhost:47800/api/v1/bacnet/devices/0/objects?properties=present-value&properties=object-name'
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
r = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
data = json.loads(r.decode('utf-8'))

time=time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))

result = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['objects'])
result_tri = result.reindex(columns=[time,'object-name','present-value'])
```

Current result

```py
   Fri Mar 29 09:47:36 2019        object-name  present-value
0                       NaN    Température_1 0          660.0
1                       NaN       Humidité_1 1          497.0
2                       NaN       Pression_1 2          497.0
3                       NaN     Vitesse_Vent 3          497.0
4                       NaN       Luminosité 4          497.0
5                       NaN       Etat_Pompe 3            0.0
6                       NaN  Greisch_Simulator            NaN
7                       NaN  networkPort 30800            NaN
```

Desired result

```py
                       Time        object-name  present-value
0  Fri Mar 29 09:47:36 2019    Température_1 0          660.0
1  Fri Mar 29 09:47:36 2019       Humidité_1 1          497.0
2  Fri Mar 29 09:47:36 2019       Pression_1 2          497.0
3  Fri Mar 29 09:47:36 2019     Vitesse_Vent 3          497.0
4  Fri Mar 29 09:47:36 2019       Luminosité 4          497.0
5  Fri Mar 29 09:47:36 2019       Etat_Pompe 3            0.0
6  Fri Mar 29 09:47:36 2019  Greisch_Simulator            NaN
7  Fri Mar 29 09:47:36 2019  networkPort 30800            NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
result_tri = result.reindex(columns=['Time','object-name','present-value'])
result_tri['Time'] = time
```

Comment: can you please accept the answer if that works for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can add new column in your df directly.

When you are doing

```
 result_tri = result.reindex(columns=[time,'object-name','present-value'])

**you actually doing** 

result_tri = result.reindex(columns="Fri Mar 29 09:47:36 2019",'object-name','present-value']
```

**time** is variable in you method which gets replaced with the value you have assigned to it.

you just need to do:

```
result = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['objects'])
result["time"] = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
result = result.reindex(columns=['Time','object-name','present-value'])
```